# Who writes necessary code for community?

Tags: discussion, community

See this profile of [community](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

I understood that it is not a person. But once in a while pushes unanswered questions to the top etc.,

But who writes the code and maintains it for our main Hinduism site?  Is it our own moderators or someone else?

Comment: Related: [Who is the community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/206319) . Also our moderators only moderate the site.

Answer (score 4):

They are Stack Exchange developers, **not community moderators.**

Visit the FAQ: [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/260388) and refer [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) for further information or question-answers about community user.

> understood that it is not a person. But once in a while pushes unanswered questions to the top etc.,

Yes, it sometimes does network-wide corrections e.g. it once actively replaced `http:` with `https://` when [SE adopted network wide https](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/260388) and redirected all child meta traffic from `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com`; recently it had been modifying posts for as [switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/260388).

*[Community user bumps questions to home page based on certain criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/260388)*:

> The Community user will bump non-negatively scored, open questions every hour that have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that.
>
> - Questions are picked randomly from the top-viewed questions with last activity more than 30 days ago.
> - Once a question is bumped, it will be ineligible for bumping for the next 120 days, unless it receives new activity after the last bump. (Bumping a question counts as new activity, so at a given time,questions bumped within the last 30 days are guaranteed not to be
>   bumped.)
> - The maximum number of unanswered questions bumped per hour depends on the site: 4 per hour on Stack Overflow, 2 per hour on Super User
>   and Server Fault, and 1 per hour on Meta Stack Exchange and all other
>   sites.
> - Some sites have limits on how many auto-bumped questions can appear on the homepage. Once the limit is reached, no more questions will be bumped until one or more bumped questions disappears off the homepage.

---

Whenever you find question is edited by community user, you can check revisions to find out the reason why question is edited i.e some correction or bump.